# How add values in different objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

How can I access only the first `@NOTIFICATION_OPENED` key?

How can I sum both values of `@NOTIFICATION_OPENED`?

This is my AJAX request:

```
$.getJSON("myapiurl", function(notificationData) {
  $.each(notificationData.data, function(index, value) {
    if (value["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]) {
      var notificationOpened = value["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]
    } else 
      notificationOpened = 0;

    var val = {
      "notificationOpened": notificationOpened
    }
    _data.push(val)
  });
}
```

This is the data I retrieve from the API using the above request:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "date": 1577836800000,
    "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
    "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
  }, {
    "date": 1577923200000,
    "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
  }]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access only the first @NOTIFICATION_OPENED key?

Simply take the first element of `data`, and then take the value of `@NOTIFICATION_OPENED`. for example:

```js
var notification = {
    "data": [{
        "date": 1577836800000,
        "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
        "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
    }, {
        "date": 1577923200000,
        "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
    }]
}

var firstNotificationData = notification.data[0]
var firstNotificationOpenedData = firstNotificationData["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]
console.log(firstNotificationOpenedData)
```

> How can I sum both values of @NOTIFICATION_OPENED?

You can use `reduce` to summarize the total of notification opened. for example:

```js
var notification = {
    "data": [{
        "date": 1577836800000,
        "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
        "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
    }, {
        "date": 1577923200000,
        "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
    }]
}

var totalNotificationOpened = notification.data.reduce(function (acc, d) {
    return acc + d["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]
}, 0)

console.log(totalNotificationOpened)
```

Answer (score -2):

I have added a square bracket to make it valid JSON:

```
const data = 
[
  {
    "date": 1577836800000,
    "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
    "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
  },
  {
   "date": 1577923200000,
   "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
  }
 ]

let nSent   = data[0]["@NOTIFICATION_SENT"]
let nOpened = data[0]["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]
let mySum   = nSent+nOpened

alert(mySum)
```

This will produce an alert with the sum 63033